# how to continue import sql file with remaining data using command line process?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql file which size is 2.36GB, 
after importing 500 MB data,
my system is shutdown due to power supply die, how can i continue after 500 MB data, 
is there any solution?

I used this command:-

```
mysql -uroot -p client_data < C:/Users/uradeshk/Desktop/client_data.sql
```

Comment: What do you mean by power problem? Did the power supply die or are your resources used up?

Comment: yes "power supply die"

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you have to restart. Since its a import of a sql file, you have to take the entire file.

Clear the table you inserted 500 MB into, unless it has `DROP` , `CREATE` statement in the file, then it will drop the table before it creates a new one.

```
TRUNCATE client_data;

mysql -uroot -p client_data < C:/Users/uradeshk/Desktop/client_data.sql
```